# react boilerplate: dispatched action not being reduced in saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga, react-boilerplate

using [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate) i have a saga that is saving data to the server correctly.  I want to put in a warning for a delayed-save warning (before it time outs completely).  To simulate this i have a 5 second wait on the server and a 1 second wait before the warning starts.

I have tried a number of options with this, but the crux of the problem is the action: *autoSaveTimeOutAction* dispatched during the timeout function is not being reduced in the reducer function.

My question is why would this happen? and how can I get it to work?

here is my output:

```
10:26:04.523 client.js:62 [HMR] connected
10:26:06.722 sagas.js?7e80********:111 attemptAutoSaveSaga starts
10:26:06.722 actions.js:111 autoSaveInitiatedAction
10:26:07.725 actions.js:119 autoSaveTimeOutAction
10:26:11.890 actions.js:127 autoSaveSuccessAction
10:26:11.891 reducer.js:72 Reducer: ACTIONS.API.AUTOSAVE.SUCCESS
```

and the code excerpts:

```
saga.js ....
export function* attemptAutoSaveSaga() {
  let autoSaveTimeOut;
  console.log('attemptAutoSaveSaga starts');
  try {
    const dataToSave = yield select(apiFirstNonSentSyncingSelector());
    yield put(autoSaveInitiatedAction(dataToSave));
    const url = `${API.URL}subjects/auto_save`;
    const options = {
      method: API.METHODS.POST,
      credentials: 'include',
      body: JSON.stringify(dataToSave),
    };
    autoSaveTimeOut = setTimeout(() => { put(autoSaveTimeOutAction(dataToSave)); }, 1000);
    const payload = yield call(request, url, options);
    yield (put(autoSaveSuccessAction(payload)));
    clearTimeout(autoSaveTimeOut);

  } catch (error) {
    clearTimeout(autoSaveTimeOut);
    ...
  }
}
export function* autoSaveSaga() {
  const watcher = yield takeLatest(ACTIONS.API.AUTOSAVE.REQUESTED, attemptAutoSaveSaga);
  yield take(LOCATION_CHANGE);
  yield cancel(watcher);
}


reducer.js
...
    case ACTIONS.API.AUTOSAVE.SUCCESS: {
       console.log('Reducer: ACTIONS.API.AUTOSAVE.SUCCESS');
...
    case ACTIONS.API.AUTOSAVE.TIMEOUT: {
      console.log('Reducer: ACTIONS.API.AUTOSAVE.TIMEOUT');
      return state;
    }
...


actions.js

...
export function autoSaveInitiatedAction(payload) {
  console.log('autoSaveInitiatedAction');
  return ({
    type: ACTIONS.API.AUTOSAVE.INITIATED,
    payload,
  });
}

export function autoSaveTimeOutAction(payload) {
  console.log('autoSaveTimeOutAction');
  return ({
    type: ACTIONS.API.AUTOSAVE.TIMEOUT,
    payload,
  });
}

export function autoSaveSuccessAction(payload) {
  console.log('autoSaveSuccessAction');
  return {
    type: ACTIONS.API.AUTOSAVE.SUCCESS,
    payload,
  };
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

to solve this i needed to fork the delay, not use a javascript timeout at all and cancel the task when the server data was successfully returned.

```
function* delayStart(dataToSave) {
  yield call(delay, 1000);
  yield put(autoSaveTimeOutAction(dataToSave));
}

export function* attemptAutoSaveSaga() {
  let delayStartTask;
  try {
    const dataToSave = yield select(apiFirstNonSentSyncingSelector());
    console.log('attemptAutoSaveSaga starts');
    yield put(autoSaveInitiatedAction(dataToSave));  // this is to set sent and timestamp.
    const url = `${API.URL}subjects/auto_save`;
    const options = {
      method: API.METHODS.POST,
      credentials: 'include',
      body: JSON.stringify(dataToSave),
    };
    delayStartTask = yield fork(delayStart, dataToSave);
    const payload = yield call(request, url, options);
    yield (put(autoSaveSuccessAction(payload)));
    yield cancel(delayStartTask);

  } catch (error) {
    yield cancel(delayStartTask);
    ...
```